# PHP to MSSQL Connection is failing because my MSSQL password contains $ special character in it

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

My Connection is failing because the password contains $ in it. How to connect the database without changing it.

```
<?php    
$servername = "MYSERVER";   
$uid = "xxxxxx"; 
$pwd = "1234$67890";
$databasename = "MSCorpInventory"; 
$connectionInfo = array ( "Database"=> $databasename, "UID"=> $uid, "PWD"=> $pwd );   
/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    
$con = sqlsrv_connect ( $servername, $connectionInfo );  
if( $con ) {
echo "Connection established.<br />";
}else{
echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
//die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

Comment: Use single quotes when you assign it to `$pwd`?  `$pwd = '1234$67890';` - Although when I `var_dump($pwd);` I don't see any problem with it when using double-quotes, unless your actual password has the dollar-sign followed by a letter to make a valid PHP variable name, but then I get an "undefined variable" error on that line.

Comment: tried with single quotes also, same error. when I use var_dump($pwd) in 
$connectionInfo = array ( "Database"=> $databasename, "UID"=> $uid, "PWD"=> var_dump($pwd) ); it just displays the password. no luck.

Comment: Which driver are you using? There's a note on the Microsoft connection options against "PWD" that says "(not supported in the PDO_SQLSRV driver)". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/connection-options?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Have a look at the SQL Server's logs; are they *actually* stating that the password is wrong, or is it a different authentication error?

Comment: Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: 172.xx.xxx.xx]

Answer (score 1):

Your $pwd is Commented

You have to remove // before $pwd

Comment: ohh yah sorry :D

Comment: I removed the committed // before $pwd in line 4. still facing the same error.

Comment: What is the error send us but times the error message

Comment: Undefined variable: m5 in D:\Inetpub\WWWRoot\windows\mssqldbconfig.php on line 4

Comment: Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: 172.xx.xxx.xx]

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the " with ', because with " PHP is searching for a variable (beginning with $).

```
$pwd = '1234$67890';
```

OR you can escape the $

```
$pwd = "1234\$67890";
```

Comment: I cannot change the password as Im not the admin.  Tried using / before $ character,  it just throws "Connection could not be established." error message as in my IF loop.

Comment: not /, you need to use \

Comment: have you thought about the fact that the password itself might be wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I used \ this slash, no luck. password is correct, I have validated the same by connecting the SQL Studio.

Comment: what is the output from sqlsrv_errors()?

Comment: Login failed for user 'xxxxxx'. Reason: Attempting to use an NT account name with SQL Server Authentication. [CLIENT: 172.xx.xxx.xx]

Comment: well then we are searching the error on a complete wrong end. the message tells you, that you are using windows credentials (nt account) to log into the sql server which expects sql server user credentials.